# Creating a file where I can store other files in VB

Tags: vb.net, file

I hope you are having a great day,

Sorry for the weird title but I don't really know which is the correct name for the thing that I am trying to do, my intention is to create like a Project file, like that one created in LabVIEW (.lvproj) where you can store files like .vi, I don't know if this is possible to do in VB, what I am trying to do is creating a file explorer where the user can see all the documents that can be added to the Project file.

Comment: Can you open an .lvproj file in a text editor and see something meaningful? If not, can you open it with a zip archive program (e.g. [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/)) and see something meaningful?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, this is what shows me:

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Project Type="Project" LVVersion="17008000">
 <Item Name="My Computer" Type="My Computer">
  <Property Name="server.app.propertiesEnabled" Type="Bool">true</Property>
  <Property Name="server.control.propertiesEnabled" Type="Bool">true</Property>
  <Property Name="server.tcp.enabled" Type="Bool">false</Property>
  <Property Name="server.tcp.port" Type="Int">0</Property>
  <Property Name="server.tcp.serviceName" Type="Str">My Computer/VI Server</Property> [...]

Comment: Have a look at a .vbproj file to see that XML can be used to store the locations of all the files in a VB.NET project. You can make your own XML file with the items you need in it. (Ideally, you would make an XSD file to go with it.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thank you so much for your help! Now I understand a little bit more how it works.

Comment: You can also save an entire file as Base64 in your XML.

Comment: @AndrewMorton First thing, I'm not *suggesting*, I'm informing. Second thing, for example the Project's `.resx` files store Bitmap (or other binary data) like that. HTML pages hand over Bitmaps    like that -- *Surely no!* is undefined.

Comment: @Jimi The type of file that I am trying to save inside the personalized extention are csv files

Comment: `dim csvBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes([The CSV file path])`, if you want to test this method. Write it back with `File.WriteAllBytes([The file path], Convert.FromBase64String([The value of an XML node])`. -- If you want to directly show the content in a UI when you read it back, you need to know the Encoding used to store the original file.